# replace a pattern to extract an image url from data php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to figure it out how to extract the url from this pattern

```
![enter image description here][1] [1]: http://www.codefixup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern-matching-in-php.png
```

I just need the http part so I can place it inside an image tag. The image description could change, how can I do it with regex or preg_replace?

Comment: Do you only want canonical URLs? I.E you only want URLs that start with `http` or do you also want URLs like `www.google.com`

Comment: I need the whole after "[1]:", the http://...someurl until space since te pattern above will be inside a text.

Comment: Example: Hi boy, how are you? This is my cat ![enter image description here][1] [1]: http://www.somewebsite.com/images/mycat.jpg I hope you love it.

Comment: @jose -- I added an answer that should get what you need, assuming the format is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to capture the entire url the following should work

```
(?:\: )(?P<URL>.*)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/aV1fJ7/1

Note this would NOT work if you had a description that was like "Check out this cool dog: "

Or something along those lines.

I can make this more specific by doing...

```
(?:\[\d+]\: )(?P<URL>.*)
```

Live example of this working with more specific one:  https://regex101.com/r/aV1fJ7/2

Example 3 to pull from an img src="" tag

```
(?:src=\")(?P<URL>.*)\"
```

https://regex101.com/r/aV1fJ7/3

And some example code showing how to capture, transform and output an image tag:

```
<?php

$urlstring ='![enter image description here][1] [1]: http://www.codefixup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern-matching-in-php.png';
$regex = '/ (?:\[\d+\]\: )(?P<URL>.*)/';
//echo $regex.'--'.$urlstring;
if (preg_match($regex, $urlstring, $matches)) {
    echo "img src=\"".$matches[1]."\"";
} else {
   echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
}

?>
```

Comment: How about turning  ![enter image description here][1] [1]: http://somewebsite.com/images/mycat.jpg into <img src="somewebsite.com/images/mycat.jpg ">

Comment: You want to extract the part after src?

Comment: Added to pull from src

Comment: No actually your answer is what I needed, to extract the url part, what happens is that I have a dynamic text, example "This is text that is going to be changin and it could have a reference to an image like this ![enter image description here][1] [1]: somewebsite.com/images/mycat.jpg so i need to turn that reference into an actual image"

Comment: Note that h-ttp:// part is erased by stackoverflow after the last [1]:

Comment: No for me :( I always struggle with regex specially when I am without much sleep

Comment: Sorry about the delay, had some lunch.  Answer updated

Comment: I was trying this preg_replace('/(?:\: )(?P<URL>.*)/','<img src="$1" alt="imagen">' ,$content_to_search_through) so I can produce the image without loosing the original text, it works but it keeps this part  ![enter image description here wich may change][1] [1]:

Comment: You should see the last edit to my answer, it should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Are you all set now @jose

Comment: Yes, your code did the job, I just changed a little bit to fit my purpose, because it'll be probably more than one image in a text so I need to replace the pattern above with the actual image tag. So this is what I did $output = preg_replace('/(?:\: )(?P<URL>.*)/','<img src="$1" alt="imagen">' ,$content_to_search_through);
$output = preg_replace('/^![.$[1]/','' ,$output);
$search = array('![','][1]','[1]','enter image description here');
$replacement = array(" ","","","");
$output = str_replace($search, $replacement, $output);

Comment: I don't want to loose the text sorrounding the images just replace the patter above with the the url  actual images.